# Android bulk insert syntax error near ","

Tags: android, sqlite, bulkinsert

I would appreciate a shade of enlightenment on the following code, since I just can't seem to figure out why it has a **syntax error near ","**.

I'm trying to insert multiple rows at once in a single statement. I'm targeting API 10+. If I only have one set of VALUES(...) it's all good, and the row gets inserted, but as soon as I have more than one, it sends out an exception with the syntax error message.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String insertRows = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_FRIENDS +
                " (" + KEY_USER_EMAIL + ", " + KEY_FRIEND + ", " + KEY_FRIEND_INTERACTIONS +
                       ", " + KEY_ENABLED +") VALUES ";

        int index; 
        for(index=0; index<friends.size(); ++index){
            insertRows += "('" + userAccount.getEmail() +"', ";

            Friend friend = friends.get(index);

            insertRows+= "'" + friend.getEmail() +"', ";
            insertRows+= "'" + friend.getInteractions() +"', ";

            int enabled = friend.isEnabled() ? 1 : 0;

            insertRows+= "'"+ enabled + "')";

            if(index != friends.size()-1)
                insertRows+= ",";
        }

        insertRows += ";";

        db.execSQL(insertRows);
        db.close();
```

I print the query out on my log and get:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user_email, friend_email, friend_interactions, friend_enabled) VALUES ('test2@test.com', 'vila@hotmail.com', '0', '0'),
('test2@test.com', 'anotherone@hotmail.com', '0', '0'),
('test2@test.com', 'yetanother@hotmail.com', '0', '0');
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: instead of building an insert query like this, why dont you use contentvalues and perform inserts ?? you are anyways running a loop

Comment: I thought multiple inserts would be bad for performance against a single insert with all the values.

Comment: yes, it is bad, bt i am doubting that the `,` after the first values combo causes the problem, or search for bulk insert in android and ul get a better solution using insert helper but it is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-values syntax was [added in sqlite 3.7.11](https://sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_11). Many devices [ship with an older version.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android)

For compatibility, insert only one row at a time. For performance, consider the following:

- Use [`compileStatement()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) to pre-compile your SQL and just change the bind args for each row.
- Wrap the inserts in a transaction to minimize waiting on I/O.

Comment: Will look into compileStatement() and report later.

Answer (score -1):

Similar questions have been asked:

[SQL - Syntax error near ','](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418027/sql-syntax-error-near)

It might be less of a syntax error and more of a timing/crowding error.

Comment: I saw that question and have checked for the answer. I end my query with ";" , and have no "stray" quotes.