# How do i resolve the SQL syntax error at the end this query?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-insert, bulkinsert

Novice SQL user here, trying to update an existing database. I am trying to update everything at once with the following query

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`lots`, `of`, `keys`)
VALUES ('Row', '1', 'data'),
('Row', '2', 'data')
...
('Row', 'n', 'data');
```

This results in the syntax error

```
 Syntax error near '' at line n+1
```

Which I'm not sure how to debug. I see one ten-year oldresult [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418027/sql-syntax-error-near) that suggests that multi-line insertions don't work like this, but the syntax I copied from a csv-to-sql site for a snippet of the database suggests that the way I'm doing it should work.

Comment: Some database implement multi-line inserts while others don't. Which database are you using? (looks like MySQL)

Comment: @TheImpaler yes, it is MySQL

Comment: Works for me. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3wNywKI2). Maybe you are reaching some limits of the MySQL interpreter/engine. How many lines are you trying to insert at once? How big are they?

Comment: @TheImpaler fiddle gives the same error message when I try with the real database. The data isn't publicly accessible so unfortunately I can't share the real thing.

Comment: Another idea: If you have values that include single quotes (`'`) remember that they need to be escaped by typing them twice (`''`).

Comment: No, there are none of those fine. But I do have other common pitfall charachters or phrases in strings, like &, ;, /, <sup>, </sup>, %, *. It doesn't seem like any of these need to be escaped, but I could be missing something.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?